# How can I video capture 3d apps running full screen on Linux?

Tags: linux, vulkan, screen-capture, libavcodec, obs

I'm currently using `libavcodec` and I have specified `x11grab`.

When running normally, I can even capture 60 FPS, but when I switch to a 3d application full screen (i.e. game running with *Vulkan* or *OpenGL*), the famebuffer is basically empty.
Again, not asking about encoding with *nvenc* or *vaapi*, but is there any other source I should specify instead of `x11grab`?

I would be looking at something similar to what *OBS* does when you specify the option *Window Capture*. What does *OBS* use in this case?